# Background particles and galaxy effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, effects

someone know any tutorial for does similar background effect of this image?

[image]

Comment: There are several tutorials on the web. If you want to get a good answer here, show that you actually tried something before asking a question. We are not a tutorial website. If you want to know more about the site, take a look at this http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's an interesting background choice, I gotta say. It's odd. It kinda looks like space, but those look more like dust particles, not stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a dozen ways to do this, you can achieve a pretty similar effect by just playing around with the gradient tool, then any cloud brush or really transparent cloud stock photo, and finally by layering up a paper or even cork texture, making it black and white, and putting it on multiply or incrustation. Experimentation is key.

Comment: Thanks, I can do this finally https://s9.postimg.org/qv6l84gz3/sid.png

Comment: Glad it helped you, you're welcome